# Appending List Elements in write.table

Tags: r

I have a list of what are essentially tables of different variables, with a reproducible dummy example below (it's a little ugly, but it gets the idea across).

```
results <- list()
for(ii in names(iris)[1:4]) {
  mytab <- table(iris[,i] > mean(iris[,i]), iris$Species)
  myp <- chisq.test(mytab)$p.value
  results[[ii]] <- as.data.frame(cbind(mytab, P.value=myp))
  results[[ii]] <- tibble::rownames_to_column(results[[ii]], ii)
}
```

In a previous version R (at least 4.0), I used to be able to do something like:

```
lapply(results, function(x) write.table(x, "myfile.txt", append=T, sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F))
```

which would generate a file called `myfile.txt` and fill it with all of my tables, much like the list of printed tables from results. I've had this code (which was functioning as expected) since at least the end of 2021. However, I now get the error:

```
Error in write.table(x, "myfile.txt", append = T, sep = "\t", quote = T,  : 
  (converted from warning) appending column names to file
```

And to some extent I get it -- the column names I'm using aren't identical to what I'm appending, but I don't really care for my purposes. I just want my printed list of tables. Is there a way to force appending irrespective of mismatched column names? I've tried using `col.names=NA` but then receive the error that using col.names=NA with row.names=F "makes no sense". Do I need to resign myself to using functions like `sink` for this? I'd really like everything to remain tab-separated if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be [baked-in](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7aa0984a0197bb4b4b28d07d66c37656af9ce949/src/library/utils/R/write.table.R#L122-L129), depending solely on the `col.names` and `append` arguments and no easy way to squelch it *there*.

In general it's just a warning, but since it was elevated to `Error` status, that suggests you've set [`options(warn = 2)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) or higher. It's not a factor for these resolutions (which result in no warning being emitted and therefore no escalation to an error).

1. Suppress it and all other warnings (for good or bad):

   ```r
   write.table(data.frame(a=1,b=2), "quux.csv", append=T, sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F)
   # Error in write.table(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), "quux.csv", append = T,  : 
   #   (converted from warning) appending column names to file

   suppressWarnings(write.table(data.frame(a=1,b=2), "quux.csv", append=T, sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F))
   ### nothing emitted, file appended
   ```
2. Suppress *just that warning*, allowing others (since suppressing all can hide other issues):

   ```r
   withCallingHandlers(
     write.table(data.frame(a=1,b=2), "quux.csv", append=T, sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F),
     warning = function(w) {
       if (grepl("appending column names to file", conditionMessage(w))) { 
         invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
       }
     })
   ### nothing emitted, file appended

   withCallingHandlers(
     write.table(data.frame(a=1,b=2), "quux.csv", append=T, sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F),
     warning = function(w) {
       if (grepl("something else", conditionMessage(w))) { 
         invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
       }
     })
   # Error in write.table(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), "quux.csv", append = T,  : 
   #   (converted from warning) appending column names to file
   ```

Comment: Yep, this is the answer. In the same environment, I was working on some other analyses and running into the same issue where I had errors converted from warnings. I read about the `options(warn=2)`, restarted my session to clear whatever settings I had going, and my code works like expected. I have no idea how it got set, since I don't often play with options settings. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to use [`write.list()` from the erer package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/erer/versions/3.1/topics/write.list):

```r
library(erer)
#> Loading required package: lmtest
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

results <- list()
for(ii in names(iris)[1:4]) {
  mytab <- table(iris[,ii] > mean(iris[,ii]), iris$Species)
  myp <- chisq.test(mytab)$p.value
  results[[ii]] <- as.data.frame(cbind(mytab, P.value=myp))
  results[[ii]] <- tibble::rownames_to_column(results[[ii]], ii)
}
write.list(z = results, file = "myfile.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
read.csv("~/Desktop/myfile.txt")
#>          Result Sepal.Length setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 1  Sepal.Length        FALSE     50         24         6 8.373761e-18
#> 2  Sepal.Length         TRUE      0         26        44 8.373761e-18
#> 3                                                                    
#> 4        Result  Sepal.Width setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 5   Sepal.Width        FALSE      8         42        33  1.24116e-11
#> 6   Sepal.Width         TRUE     42          8        17  1.24116e-11
#> 7                                                                    
#> 8        Result Petal.Length setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 9  Petal.Length        FALSE     50          7         0 9.471374e-28
#> 10 Petal.Length         TRUE      0         43        50 9.471374e-28
#> 11                                                                   
#> 12       Result  Petal.Width setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 13  Petal.Width        FALSE     50         10         0 4.636126e-26
#> 14  Petal.Width         TRUE      0         40        50 4.636126e-26
#> 15

# You can also specify the table names, e.g.
write.list(z = results, file = "myfile2.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, t.name = 1:4)
read.csv("~/Desktop/myfile2.txt")
#>    Result Sepal.Length setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 1       1        FALSE     50         24         6 8.373761e-18
#> 2       1         TRUE      0         26        44 8.373761e-18
#> 3                                                              
#> 4  Result  Sepal.Width setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 5       2        FALSE      8         42        33  1.24116e-11
#> 6       2         TRUE     42          8        17  1.24116e-11
#> 7                                                              
#> 8  Result Petal.Length setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 9       3        FALSE     50          7         0 9.471374e-28
#> 10      3         TRUE      0         43        50 9.471374e-28
#> 11                                                             
#> 12 Result  Petal.Width setosa versicolor virginica      P.value
#> 13      4        FALSE     50         10         0 4.636126e-26
#> 14      4         TRUE      0         40        50 4.636126e-26
#> 15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>